# Translating a model stored in BIM360

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge

I'd like to translate a revit file that is stored in BIM360 to IFC format.
So I found the revit file in BIM360 using the *HubsApi*, *ProjectsApi* and *FolderApi* classes from the .NET client API nuget package:
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client

I found the URN of the file using the *GetFolderContentsAsync* method of *FoldersApi*, but when I try  to use it with the *TranslateAsync* method of *DerivativesApi* class, I get this error:

> Error calling Translate: {"diagnostic":"Internal server error when get
> design description with code 400"}

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On BIM360, you access model via their Version, not the Item. You seems to tell to wanted translate the Item which may list several versions.

[GetFolderContent](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-contents-GET/) returns items, Use the item URN for the next call. Something like: urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:hC6k4hndRWaeIVhIjvHu8w

[GetItemVersions](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-versions-GET/) will return version's URN. Something like: urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.b909RzMKR4mhc3O7UBY_8g?version=2

This is the one you need.